maximization of utility function with random resource increments
My area of knowledge lies outside this problem that I recently encountered. I would like to get general advice on whether this is a known problem, if there are any known algorithms, etc.
Let the available resources at time $n$ be denoted by $b_n$. At each time, there is a random increment of resources by an amount $a_n$ where the pdf/pmf of $a_n$ is at hand. At time $n$, an amount of the resources $p_n$ is spent. The utility of the spent resources is a general function $f(p)$ where $f(0)=0$, and $f(\cdot)$ is monotonically increasing.
the objective is to produce a policy of how much resources that should be spent at time $n$. It may be assumed here that the increment at time $n$ occurs prior to spending the $p_n$ resources; but this is not critical.
Thus, available resources behave as
$$b_n=b_{n-1}+a_n-p_n$$
and is conditioned to always satistfy $b_n\geq 0,\forall n$.
Thus, I need to determine $p_n$ as a function of $b_{n-1}+a_n$ to maximize
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} f(p_n)$$
where $N$ may grow without bounds. The initital condition $b_0$ is irrelevant, but can be set to $b_0=0$.
We may assume a discrete case, in which all variables belong to the set of natural numbers $0,1,2,...$, or a continuous case - whatever is easiest.
